# Not able find correct Xpath for Amazon.com , list page "Brand" filter

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium web driver I am trying to automate `https://www.amazon.com/` . On the list page , I am not able to find the **Xpath** for "**Brand**" filter. If I check manually, the mentioned xpath looks correct "`//div[@id='brandsRefinements']`" . But when I use it in script it says element not found.

Not able to go ahead and select the filter because of this.

Comment: Where is Brand on amazon.com ?

Comment: brandsRefinements is not present on https://www.amazon.com/ when you launch it. Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `xpath` is correct. I have written below snippet of code and it is working fine.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=jeans+for+men&crid=416FMJ6OYA40&sprefix=jeans%2Caps%2C391&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_5");

WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='brandsRefinements']"));

System.out.println(element.getTagName());
```

Comment: Thank you ,  The xpath was correct but I had some issue with TestNg. Thanks for responding.